# Access denied running program in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

so far I have only used Linux to write C++ code, but I want to learn to do it in Windows as well using CMake to simplify things.

To get started, I have written the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)  
PROJECT( CMakeWin )

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# find opencv and set variables
Set(OpenCV_DIR C:/Users/Erik/Documents/Libraries/opencv/build)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)


#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME}
src/main.cpp 
)


TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

When I run CMake (using Visual Studio 11 configuration) it seems to work properly, but when I open the CMakeWin.sln project and build and then run it, I get

```
Unable to start program C:\..... The system cannot find the file 
specified.
```

But I have also received

```
access denied.
```

When I go directly to the Release or Debug folder and run

```
CMakeWin.exe
```

it runs as it shall. What can the problem be?

EDIT:

To avoid making visual studio trying to run ALL_BUILD, I had to set CMakeWin as the StartUp project. See https://simtk.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=3676 and comments below.

Comment: Don't think here is something related to `c++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, open up the project properties dialog (right click on the project in the solution explorer pane and choose properties). Go to Debug and see what the command line to run the app is. That is most likely what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work after some digging, but why was it looking for ALLWORK instead of CMakeWin.exe in the debug folder? Should I change anything in my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Alas, I've not used much CMake and never had problems when I have. My knowledge is more on the visual studio side. I suspect you will need to change something in the CMakeLists.txt file. Is there anything related to ALLWORK in your system (or in your environment variables)?

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Studio, right-click your project and mark it as 'Set as Startup project'.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

CMake uses the same configuration as the one you are used on Linux. The common structure for simple projects is to have the sources files, compiled files and executable in same directory. So you can compile and run from the same directory.

MSVC default configuration (I do not know how to change that, and I would not dare to) uses one folder per *configuration*. You can have as many as them as you want, common ones would be DebugUnicode, ReleaseUnicode, DebugAnsi and ReleaseAnsi.

The common structure is :

- top level folder : solution

  - one folder per project in the solution (one solution can contain multiple projects) : source files

    - a `res` folder (optional) for resource files (icons, etc.)
    - a folder per *configuration*, Debug + Release : object and executable files

So it is *by design* that executable files are not in same folder as the solution. You can execute them from there by giving their relative path: `Debug\project.exe`

Answer (score 1):

1.Close the solution.
2.Close Visual Studio.
3.Reopen your project.

This worked for me.